# Is it save to put array in cookie

Tags: php

```
$apply_id=1111;

if(isset($_COOKIE['apply'])){
    $apply_cookie=$_COOKIE['apply'];
    @$apply_cookie=gzuncompress($_COOKIE['apply']);}
else{$apply_cookie=array();}

$apply_cookie = @explode(',', $apply_cookie);
if($apply_cookie === false){$apply_cookie = array();}
else{
    $count=count($apply_cookie);
    for($n=0; $n<$count; $n++){
        if(!is_numeric($apply_cookie[$n])){unset($apply_cookie[$n]);}
    }   
}

//HAVE COOKIE
if(@in_array($apply_id, $apply_cookie)==TRUE){
    echo "COOKIE=TRUE<BR>";
    print_r($apply_cookie);
}
else{
    //NO COOKIE,DB HAVE RECORDED
    $db=TRUE; //QUERY HERE,SET TRUE OR FALSE FOR NOW
    if($db==TRUE){
        echo "COOKIE=FALSE; DB=TRUE";

        $apply_cookie[]=$apply_id;  
        $apply_cookie=implode(',', $apply_cookie);
        $apply_cookie=gzcompress($apply_cookie);    
        setcookie("apply", $apply_cookie, time()+3600*24*60);

    }
    else{
        //NO COOKIE,NO RECORDED
        echo "COOKIE=FALSE, DB=FALSE";

        $apply_cookie[]=$apply_id;
        $apply_cookie=implode(',', $apply_cookie);
        $apply_cookie=gzcompress($apply_cookie);    
        setcookie("apply", $apply_cookie, $apply_cookie, time()+3600*24*60);
    }
}
```

I set up a cookie to check if user have been applied. If cookie have  the record. It will skip the query. If no cookie or no record than query db and update the cookie.

`gzcompress`(make it smaller)->`explode`(array)->`is_number`(only allow number) ->`in_array`(check if it exist)

is this secure enough? (I was using `serialize` before, but it seems a bit insecure)

It's only check cookie record exist or not, if not do query and update the cookie

Comment: Cookies is a free to edit storage, so you cannot trust anything retrieved from cookies.

Comment: "secure enough" as in...? If you're trying to prevent the user from reading/changing it, then no.

Comment: i have do lots of checking, remove the empty array and it only allow numbers

Comment: why don't you save this data on the server side and just use a cookie for the identification purpose

Comment: Why don't you use `$_SESSION` instead of `$_COOKIE` ? ...

Comment: i do have record at server side, this just help me to reduce the query. if cookie have record than dont query, if not query

Comment: Or you should just use `json_encode` / `json_decode`

Comment: @user2178521: Sounds like you want to perform caching. Cookies come at a cost to you know -- the more data you store client side (and there is a pretty small limit on cookies), the more data is being sent back and forth with every request. You might consider caching to a file, or memcached, if this *really* is a performance issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better solution is:

```
<?php

$apply_id = 1111;

switch (true) {

case !isset($_COOKIE['apply']):
case ($apply_cookie = @gzuncompress($_COOKIE['apply'])) === false:
case !is_array($apply_cookie = json_decode($apply_cookie)):
    $apply_cookie = array();
    break;
default:
    $tmp = array();
    foreach ($apply_cookie as $c) {
        if (is_string($c) && is_numeric($c)) {
            $tmp[] = $c;
        }
    }
    $apply_cookie = $tmp;
}

if (in_array($apply_id, $apply_cookie)) {
    // HAVE COOKIE
    echo 'COOKIE = TRUE<br />'.PHP_EOL;
    echo nl2br(print_r($apply_cookie, true));
} else {
    $db = true;
    // HAVE NO COOKIE
    if ($db) {
        // HAVE RECORDED
        $apply_cookie[] = $apply_id;
        setcookie('apply', gzcompress(json_encode($apply_cookie)), time()+3600*24*60);
        echo 'COOKIE = FALSE, DB = TRUE<br />'.PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        // HAVE NO RECORDED
        $apply_cookie[] = $apply_id;
        setcookie('apply', gzcompress(json_encode($apply_cookie)), time()+3600*24*60);
        echo 'COOKIE = FALSE, DB = FALSE<br />'.PHP_EOL;
    }
}
```

**Note**: You have to `setcookie` before any outputs.